# Intuitive/geometric way to show that $\sinh x =-i\sin ix$ and $\cosh x=\cos ix$?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

> $$\begin{align}
> \sinh(x)&=-i\sin(ix) \\
> \cosh(x)&=\phantom{-i}\cos(ix)
> \end{align}$$
>
> Why are these identities true?
>
> Other than using algebra and formulas, is there a more intuitive/geometric way to show that the above is true?

**Attempt**
The equation of a unit circle is:  $x^2+y^2=1$
The equation of a unit hyperbola is:  $x^2-y^2=1$
If $y\rightarrow iy$, then a circle will become a hyperbola.

For a circle: $y=\sin(θ)$
For a hyperbola: $iy=\sinh(θ)$ ---> $y=-i\sinh(θ)$

For a circle: $x=\cos(θ)$
For a hyperbola: $x=\cosh(θ)$

But obviously $\cos(x)=\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(x)=-i\sinh(x)$ are wrong.

Comment: Do you know Eulers identity?

Comment: Yes I know Eulers identity

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get much geometric intuition for what $\sin(ix)$ should even mean in the first place, without passing through its connection to the exponential.

Comment: The geometric definition of the hyperbolic functions is a little trickier than just going $y=i\sinh\theta$. See the diagram at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function (but I agree with @Ian about the likelihood of success of a purely geometric argument).

Comment: Really? But I'm so close. All I need is an $i$ inside the trig function, and I can't seem to find where my attempt went wrong. Also, what do you mean by "passing through its connection to the exponential"?

Comment: I think @Ian means using $\sin z=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/(2i)$, or $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$.